# Buzzing noise coming from inside my computer while playing games

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, computer-building, noise

I just finished building my PC like a week ago. I just noticed there is a faint buzzing noise while playing a game (the noise also comes out from my speakers). I tried to pinpoint the noise and turns out it's coming from inside my computer.

The buzzing noise sounds like it's coming from either power supply or graphic card. I'm assuming it's the graphic card, because the power supply is already making a noise (like a hard disk. I searched a little, and it's a common problem for XFX Pro750w Core edition).

There is also another issue; when I turn off/on the power supply (switch), I hear a bump noise from my speakers.

I don't mind the noise but I want to make sure it is not something bad. Is it safe to ignore it?

I've uploaded the sound file which you can hear the noise (when I start a game): http://www.mediafire.com/download/njgxdb7qbkrmaxb/2.wma
(There are 2 sounds: power supply and graphic card. The power supply's noise sounds like a hard disk, while the graphic card sounds buzzing.)

Thanks in advance...

Specs:

```
Motherboard Gigabyte Z77-D3H
Processor: i7 3770 3.4ghz
Graphic card: XFX HD7850
PSU: XFX Pro 750w Core edition
```

Comment: The bump noise from the speakers is common. Though it definitely does not happen with every system. The fan noise from the power supply, as you know, is fan noise. Buzzing usually occurs when a fan does not spin freely. Is there anything touching the fan to keep it from spinning freely? Otherwise, is the fan accessible? If so, to test if the fan is making the noise, which always the culprit, while the computer is on and the fan is spinning (of course). lightly touch the center of the spinning fan so it slows the fan to a stop, only for a moment, if the buzzing stops, there is your answer.

Comment: @Jack Are you talking about the power supply? That noise is a common problem for that model. I cannot touch the power supply's fan as it's upside down (HAF 912 case). Besides, you can also hear the noise coming from the speakers, I don't think it is a fan noise problem.

Comment: The finger on the fan was for the GPU. I was aware about the PSU fan noise. The buzzing from the speakers, I have only had that problem occur a few times and the power brick was at fault.

Comment: @Jack I just checked, and it is not the gpu's fan. I even changed the velocity with Catalyst Control Center, to 65%, and there is no buzzing noise. I also plugged my computer directly to the wall, and the noise was still there.

Comment: Just to clarify, you reduced the fan's RPM and the buzzing is gone? Sounds like the issues are small ones now, just fan noise....and speaker buzzing. Onto that, when you plugged the computer directly into the wall, is that the correct the speaker buzzing? Yes like gronostaj mentioned it is normal with some speaker systems, though I would prefer to not have that ever present buzzing, I lived with it for a long while with my original 2.1 set up, it disappeared when I went to my 5.1 I have now, what a difference!

Comment: @Jack Sorry I meant that even at higher RPM there is no noise. GPU's fan is usually at 20% when nothing is being rendered. I don't quite understand your question "when you plugged the computer directly into the wall, is that the correct the speaker buzzing?"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11969/discussion-between-jack-and-user658091)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To this day I didn't know what was the root of the problem, but that was the sound of bad capacitors/chips.

It burnt a chip on my graphic card and it damaged the motherboard. I RMA'd the PSU and motherboard.

If something is unusual, don't wait until it's too late.

Answer (score 1):

The buzzing noise from speakers and power on bump sound are normal and nothing to worry about. The one you've recorded is probably fine too. If you don't have overheating problems, I'd leave it like that for now and just check it every now and then. If it becomes louder over time, you should think about replacing graphics card's cooling.

Comment: I think I will do that. Replace the graphic card's cooling as in replace the metal case and fan?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. You can examine it before deciding to go with a new one, maybe there's some wire that touches the fan and makes that noise.

Comment: I increased the RPM of gpu's fan, and there is no buzzing noise. It only shows up when I start a game or have it focused.

Comment: What if you set it to run at 100% velocity all the time? It would make diagnosing easier if you could find any other way to trigger that sound. Or maybe it's not the GPU cooler making it, can you try with different graphics card?