# Computer shut down while playing a game

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, shutdown, computer-building, noise

**Fourth edit:**

I removed my graphic card. I installed Intel HD Graphics 4000 driver and then I did a test (graphics test). There is a similar sound like the one of my graphic card: http://www.mediafire.com/download/7dd83632kcmil17/new_sound.wma

This time I can only hear it from the speakers. I double checked the voltage regulators and 2 of them they seem a little different (like a gradient black. It's hard to describe).

The load bump from the speakers when I turn on my computer is still there.

I'm going to call where I bought these parts, but I don't know if it's the PSU or the motherboard. If anyone has some insight, thanks in advance.

---

**Fifth edit:**

I checked where the 2x12 pin connectors and 4x4 pin connectors are plugged on the motherboard, and I didn't see anything burnt, white as new.

I checked the 2x12 pin connector of my PSU, and there is a very faint burnt smell. I also checked the PSU and that smell is stronger (inside the PSU).

It's very hard to see inside without making the warranty void, but I noticed a burnt spot where the power plug is connected. I'm not sure of myself, but that really looks like burnt metal.

I asked another person if both the 2x12 connector smelled burnt. He said that only the PSU smelled burnt but he also said that PSU normally smell like that when you are using them (I haven't turned my computer in around 15 hours).

---

**Original post:**

I was worried about some strange noises when I finished building my pc ([Buzzing noise coming from inside my computer while playing games](https://superuser.com/questions/688376/buzzing-noise-coming-from-inside-my-computer-while-playing-games)).

I was ignoring the sounds until now.

I was playing GW2 just fine, until I approached a heavy intense graphics area (like in-game smoke), the computer shut itself down. I heard a loud bump from the speakers. Then it tried to turn itself on but the computer couldn't (like when the electricity goes off/on).

I tried to turn it on, but no response. At this moment, I thought my PC just completely died. Then I pushed the switch for the PSU (I/O) and unplugged and plugged my computer, and it turned on.

I don't think it's a heat issue because where I live, it's not so hot (19C ambient temperature when I played and as I'm writing this). I have a HAF 912 case with 3 fans. Hyper evo 212 as cpu fan cooler.

I have tested my PC with heavy load tests, and they all finished with good results (prime95, burnintest, OCCT (graphic)).

Also, whenever I turn on my computer there is a loud bump sound from the speakers. And when I turn it on, there is this high pitch sound increasing from the speakers, after awhile it goes away.

Is it safe to say that my PSU is dying?

Specs:

```
Motherboard Gigabyte Z77-D3H
Processor: i7 3770 3.4ghz
Graphic card: XFX HD7850
PSU: XFX Pro 750w Core edition
```

DxDiag:

```
http://pastebin.com/JvkAB26R
```

Edit:

I did a 10 minute benchmark (only graphic card), and there was this really weird sound coming from the Graphic card (it was also coming out from the speakers)): http://www.mediafire.com/download/raa8q0616fcsrad/weird_sound.wma

The test was going at around 2k frames per second. Then I did another one which was going for 100 frames per second, and the noise was different.

Apart from the weird noise, there were no problems detected.

Second edit:

I searched the motherboard and graphic card for burnt spots. To my surprise there was a burnt chip on my graphic card. Nothing on my motherboard (I thoroughly searched).

Did my PSU caused it? Was it only my graphic card to blame? What do I do now?

Third edit:

I checked the voltage regulators of my motherboard. There were no burnt spots, melted or separated metals from motherboard.

One of the voltage capacitors, had some white strings (very hard to notice, like dust), I used some compressed air, and now it's clean. Other than this, I didn't find anything unusual.

Comment: When a computer generates smoke you have a problem.  You need to find the damaged part and replace it.  working electronics do NOT generate smoke.  Audio interference could be generated by almost anything.

Comment: @Ramhound not real smoke. Smoke from GW2 game.

Comment: List your dxdiag log

Comment: @Ramhound I edited it and added the link to the dxdiag information.

Comment: Try to run a graphic benchmark for a while and see if it goes off again. 

(3dMark, Cinebench and similar... )

Comment: I would first update the driver you have a late Oct driver.  Next I would verify the temperatures while doing a benchmark

Comment: Thanks. I will update the driver. Is it risky to do any benchmark? I'm afraid my PC might catch on fire or something else.

Comment: You cannot diagnose your problem without the benchmark

Comment: @Ramhound how "heavy" the benchmark has to be? I edited my post and there was a new weird sound.

Comment: @Synetech bad capacitors of the graphic card? How do I know if it was from factory or that my PSU is faulty and that caused it?

Comment: `I did a 10 minute benchmark (only graphic card), and there was this really weird sound coming from the Graphic card (it also coming out from the speakers): http://www.mediafire.com/download/raa8q0616fcsrad/weird_sound.wma` That my friend is the [sound](https://www.google.com/search?q=capacitor+high+pitched) of [bad capacitors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_Plague). They can happen anywhere in a system. Check the video-adapter and motherboard for bulges like those in the photos in the WikiPedia article. Unfortunately a lot of manufacturers used bad caps. Request an RMA if possible.

Comment: @Synetech I found a burnt chip. I edited my post. What should I do?

Comment: Take a look at the [voltage regulators](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3qhPH.jpg) [on the motherboard](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9A98w.jpg). If they don’t look suspicious at all, then it’s probably just the video-card that is faulty, so request an [RMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_merchandise_authorization) if you are eligible.

Comment: @Synetech I checked them and updated my post. What do you mean by suspicious? Btw, thank you so much.

Comment: @Synetech I updated my post. I removed my graphic card and there is a new sound. I'm going to call where I bought them but I'm not sure what to say, PSU or motherboard.

Comment: Take a look *inside* the 2×12-pin connectors on both the motherboard and PSU cable. Do you see any [dark or even light](http://pinballzone.com/forums/DFI-PS35BL-01.jpg) [brown or black](http://forums.legitreviews.com/images/psu/1.jpg) marks? Take a sniff in the PSU through its vents, do you smell anything even remotely smokey or like “burned electronics/metal/plastic smell”?

Comment: @Synetech Thank you. I checked again and edited my post (fifth edit). There wasn't any burnt spot except for inside the PSU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As davidgo answered, it was the sound of bad capacitors/chips.

To this day, I wasn't able to pinpoint the problem. I RMA'd the motherboard and PSU. My graphic card was trashed.

It all started with a weird noise coming from the PSU and a buzzing noise coming from the speakers.

If something is unusual, don't wait until it's too late.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a dodgy (stuffed) power supply - both because turning it off, waiting and turning it on fixed it, and because of the noise and that the problem happened during heavy use.

Probably a blown cap.

Comment: Dem blown caps. All the time.

Comment: @davidgo I found a burnt chip on my graphic card. Do you think my PSU caused it? I edited my post.

Comment: I can't tell, sorry.   A picture might help, but even then I wouldn't be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your case, I set 4 checks you should do. Try resurfaces them if the problem persists look for who sold you the parts.

- Make sure your power supply is capable of powering all components of your machine;
- Make sure your graphics card is getting the correct power;
- Make sure your power supply is with whips in good condition;
- Verify that the power outlet where the stabilizer is on has ground wire.